# ViewHolder - проблема с ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

Здравствуйте. У меня такая проблема. Есть `ListView` с данными от сервера в том числе и пути к изображениям. Список строится и всё отлично, но если использовать паттерн `ViewHolder`, то изображения которые должны соответствовать своим айтемам либо им не соответсвуют, либо творится не понятно что) В общем сплошной фестиваль...Гугл подсказывает что надо использовать `AsyncTask`, а у меня логика вывода изображений построена на Picasso. Как с этим быть подскажите пожалуйста?

```
 public View elemView(int position, View convertView) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    ads_id = data.get(position).getAdsId();
    cat_id = data.get(position).getCatId();
    adsPictureID = data.get(position).getAdsPictureID();

    String catNames = dbInit.selectCatName(cat_id);
    String adsText = data.get(position).getAdsText();
    String adsHeader = data.get(position).getAdsName();
    String adsPicture = data.get(position).getAdsPicture();
    String adsCreated = data.get(position).getAdsCreated();
    String adsUserName = data.get(position).getAdsUserName();
    String adsUserLastName = data.get(position).getAdsUserLastName();

    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(adsCreated, "|");
    String names = adsUserName + " " + adsUserLastName;
    String date = tokens.nextToken();
    String time = tokens.nextToken();


    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ads_view_content, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.catName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.cat_name);
        viewHolder.adsid = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ads_id);
        viewHolder.text = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        viewHolder.header = convertView.findViewById(R.id.header);
        viewHolder.timeview = convertView.findViewById(R.id.time_ads);
        viewHolder.dateview = convertView.findViewById(R.id.date_ads);
        viewHolder.adsNames = convertView.findViewById(R.id.adsUserName);
        viewHolder.avatar = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ads_users_picture);
        viewHolder.imgFiles = data.get(position).getAdsFiles();

        viewHolder.adsGetImages = new AdsGetImages(activity, convertView, viewHolder.imgFiles, adsPictureID);
        viewHolder.adsGetImages.getAdsImagesUsers();
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.text.setText(adsText);
    viewHolder.dateview.setText(date);
    viewHolder.timeview.setText(time);
    viewHolder.adsNames.setText(names);
    viewHolder.catName.setText(catNames);
    viewHolder.header.setText(adsHeader);
    viewHolder.adsid.setText(String.valueOf(ads_id));

    getUsersAvatars.getAdsAvatars(viewHolder.avatar, adsPictureID, adsPicture);
    return convertView;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView pic;
    TextView text;
    TextView adsid;
    TextView header;
    ImageView avatar;
    TextView catName;
    TextView timeview;
    TextView dateview;
    TextView adsNames;
    AdsGetImages adsGetImages;
    ArrayList<String> imgFiles;
    ProgressBar progressAdsImgLoad;
    LinearLayout ads_imgContainer;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
}
```

AdsGetImages.class

```
public void imageView(final ImageView pic, int adsFilesWidth, int adsFilesHeight) {
    Picasso.with(context).load(URL).resize(adsFilesWidth, adsFilesHeight).centerInside()
            .into(pic, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                @Override public void onSuccess() {
                    viewHolder.progressAdsImgLoad.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } @Override public void onError() {} });
}

public void getAdsImagesUsers() {

    if(imgFiles.size() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < imgFiles.size(); i++) {
            if (!imgFiles.get(i).equals("")) {
                int adsFilesWidth, adsFilesHeight;
                viewHolder.pic = new ImageView(context);
                viewHolder.pic.setTag(imgName);
                viewHolder.pic.setLayoutParams(viewHolder.layoutParams);
                imageView(viewHolder.pic, adsFilesWidth, adsFilesHeight);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: и зачем вам эти приключения с `ListView`? Делайте всё на `RecyclerView`. Он уже из коробки содержит паттерн _ViewHolder_.
Советую смотреть 2 примера: [здесь](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/) и [здесь](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/)

Comment: Спасибо, буду использовать именно это направление

Comment: А что за переменная `URL`? Вы грузите все изображения из неё, а в коде её инициализации не видно.

Comment: @eugeneek я не весь код сюда выложил) Так то всё грузит, но как то рандомно. Думаю что RecycleView решение моей проблемы.

Comment: @Шура Балаганов спасибо) Вы мне очень помогли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать `RecyclerView` - это решение верное.